# How to change Kafka Rest Proxy CURL command in order to use it in a browser

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I'm trying out Rest Proxy in Kafka.

When I type the following url in my browser `http://192.168.0.30:8082/topics`,

I get the expected results :

```
["__confluent.support.metrics","_confluent-command","_confluent-controlcenter-5-
2-2-1-MetricsAggregateStore-changelog","_confluent-controlcenter-5-2-2-1-actual-
group-consumption-rekey","_confluent-controlcenter-5-2-2-1-expected-group-
consumption-rekey","_confluent-controlcenter-5-2-2-1-metrics-trigger-measurement-
rekey","_confluent-ksql-default__command_topic","_confluent-metrics","_confluent-
monitoring","_schemas","connect-configs","connect-offsets","connect-
statuses","default_ksql_processing_log","test","test1"]
```

**My question :** I try not to use CURL. I have the following CURL command examples . If I want to use only my browser like above, how can I change it?

I tried this, but... (How can I consume my topic `test`?)
[image]

**Just an example from a document : **

```
# Create a consumer for binary data, starting at the beginning of the topic's
# log. Then consume some data from a topic.
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v1+json" \
      --data '{"id": "my_instance", "format": "binary", "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"}' \
      http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_binary_consumer
  {"instance_id":"my_instance","base_uri":"http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_binar
y_consumer/instances/my_instance"}

$ curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.binary.v1+json" \
      http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_binary_consumer/instances/my_instance/topics/test
  [{"key":null,"value":"S2Fma2E=","partition":0,"offset":0}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers can only issue GET requests.

You could use tools like Postman or Insomnia to issue other HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

## (For further reference)

I used Postman in order to use REST Proxy for Kafka.

**1.** I subscribed to a topic `test`.

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data 
'{"topics":["test"]}' \   
http://192.168.0.30:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instanc
e/subscription
```

( I changed this CURL to fit into Postman. )

[image]

---

**2.** Then, I consumed the topic.

```
$ curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
http://192.168.0.30:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instanc
e/records
```

(I changed this CURL to fit into Postman.)

[image]